# How to move components freely in Android Studio project blueprint view

Tags: android, android-studio, components

How can you move components in Android Studio freely so that in the image below, the image and Grow are next to each other? The only option I currently have when moving them with the mouse is to change their order. I've tried changing various component attributes (height, width, padding) but I can't seem to find the problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8ec1.png)

Answer (score 1):

Take care to check which kind of Layout do you use. You are probably using `LinearLayout` and with this one, you can't place wherever you whish the components, there are placed one after the other, either vertically or either horizontally (by default). ([Take a look here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout))

To be able to set your components wherever you wish, you should check `ConstraintLayout` whose works by constraining edges of components to another components. ([Take a look here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout))

Comment: Thanks this worked but now I'm getting the error "unresolved reference: view_pager" when building.

Comment: @GrowthTracker Glad it works. Don't forget to mark this question as resolved. Now, it's not the same question, I invite you to ask your new problem with a new question with more details!